# MYSQL - Select and parse

Tags: mysql, parsing, lua, mariadb

I have my databse: public

I have my table: info

in row files of player Maria i have this:

```
['python22.dll', ''], ['python27.dll', ''], ['channel.inf', ''], ['devil.dll', ''],['is_hack.exe', '']
```

The first 4 is normal so I don't want to see them in the list .. i just want to catch the "is_hack.exe"

My mysql query to get all ( including my normal files) is:

```
query("SELECT files FROM public.info WHERE player = 'Maria' ORDER BY actual_time DESC LIMIT 0,1;")
```

I need to see all the names that are not mine. Like:

```
FILE_FROM_OUTSIDE1 = is_hack.exe
FILE_FROM_OUTSIDE2 = stackoverflow.dll
```

If you know about LUA, i can get the entire query results to LUA then begin to parse.. but how?

**EDIT:**

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_check` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `normal` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual_time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `files` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

In "files" i have all this:

```
['python22.dll', ''], ['python27.dll', ''], ['channel.inf', ''], ['devil.dll', ''],['is_hack.exe', '']
```

I just want to select the is_hack.exe .. like:  print is_hack.exe

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Why don't you just add a `WHERE` clause if you want to filter?

Comment: I edited the problem for you can see better.

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Comment: hjpotter92, we don't discuse about Moons and Stars. A programmer know what is "lua".

Comment: You could also write in all caps, since lower case letters are redundant. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @SixSense If you click on both links for lua from my comment above; you'll see that they are __both__ languages (one more esoteric than the other).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. But i think this might help:
Replace the filename_field with your col name.

```
query("SELECT files FROM public.info WHERE player = 'Maria' AND filename_field = 'is_hack.exe' ORDER BY actual_time DESC LIMIT 0,1;")
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know if this I'm right but you should not save data like this. You can create a files table and specify which user own each row. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE `playerfiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then you can retrieve data with JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM `info`
JOIN `playerfiles` ON `playerfiles.player` = `info.id`
WHERE `info.player` = 'Maria' and `playerfiles.filename` = 'THE NAME'
```

Comment: Thank you, but: If "is_hacker.exe" in next day will be: "i_changed_the_name.exe" .. ? I need to select what is NOT MINE so I must define WHAT IS MINE.